# How to Replace Or Update div based on its id

Tags: jquery

I have a div as shown

```
<div id="mycontainer">
    <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0">
         <h3>First Item</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap644" data-lastwrapquan="0">
         <h3>Second Item</h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

Could you please let me know how to replace Or add a new One if mycontainer consists of div lastwrap703

I have tried it this way

```
   $(document).on('click', '.replaceoradd', function (e) {
    // update existing  lastwrap703 if exists inside mycontainer  or add new 

    var id = "703";

    if ($("#lastwrap" + id).length == 0) {  // doesn't exists
         var html = ' <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0"><h3>Second Item</h3></div>';
        $("#mycontainer).append(html);
    }

    else {
      $( "#mycontainer.lastwrap703").replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
    }

});
```

Could you please let me know how to accomplish this

http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/28/

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in `$("mycontainer").append(html)` Is this just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had few errors, you was using .replaceadd instead #replaceadd, your was loooking for #mycontainer.lastwrap703 when was #mycontainer > #lastwrap+id, and you must close the *"* in $("#mycontainer)

Code modified:

```
$(document).on('click', '#replaceoradd', function (e) {
    // update existing  lastwrap703 if exists inside mycontainer  or add new 

    var id = "703";

    if ($("#lastwrap" + id).length == 0) {  // doesn't exists
         var html = ' <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0"><h3>Second Item</h3></div>';
        $("#mycontainer").append(html);
    }

    else {
      $( "#mycontainer > #lastwrap"+id).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
    }

});
```

An the JSFiddle fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/fpzeLa0a/

Comment: can i check under mycontainer only this way  if ($("#mycontainer #lastwrap" + id).length == 0) ??

Comment: Is the common way, you can ignore == 0 (for default 0 is false), if ($("#mycontainer #lastwrap" + id).length), is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the new html in else part. you should use `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith()`

```
 else {
  $( "#mycontainer.lastwrap703").html( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems

```
//replaceoradd is the id, so use id selector
$(document).on('click', '#replaceoradd', function (e) {

    var id = "703",
        $el = $("#lastwrap" + id);

    if ($el.length == 0) { // doesn't exists
        var html = ' <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0"><h3>Second Item</h3></div>';
        $("#mycontainer").append(html);
    } else {
        //use id selector here to find the element 
        $el.html("<h2>New heading</h2>");
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9chyLudh/)

Comment: can i check under mycontainer only this way  if ($("#mycontainer #lastwrap" + id).length == 0) ??

Comment: you should not need that as ID of an element must be unique in a document.. if there is a possibility that there could be another element with the same id somewhere else in the document you have a logical error

Comment: so taht is the reason i am checking under particular div  mycontainer  , wil that resolve the issue ??

Comment: @PreethiJain is there a possibility that another element with same id can exists somewhere else?

Comment: that should not happen... if that is the case, use another attribute or class name instead of id

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and the `if` part of your code was working fine. I noticed that your click event handler was listening to class `.replaceoradd` so I had to change it like below. Also, thanks to Milind Anantwar for pointing out the `else` part code issue; so I changed the `else` part of your code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/673h38g9/34/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#replaceoradd', function (e) {
    // update existing  lastwrap703 if exists inside mycontainer  or add new 

    var id = "703";

    if ($("#lastwrap" + id).length == 0) {  // doesn't exists

         var html = ' <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0"><h3>Second Item</h3></div>';
        $("#mycontainer").append(html);
    }

    else {

      $( "#mycontainer #lastwrap703").html( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the basic idea already, however, there are a couple of syntax errors in your code:

- First, you're missing a closing quote to your `#mycontainer` selector: `$("#mycontainer).append(html);` should be `$("#mycontainer").append(html);`
- Next, you're attaching your click handler to `.replaceoradd`, which specifies a class, but `replaceoradd` is an ID in your example. You should use `#replaceoradd`.
- Finally, your selector for `replaceWith` is slightly off, `#mycontainer.lastwrap703` specifies an element with an ID of `mycontainer` AND a class of `lastwrap703`. The correct selector for your example is `#mycontainer #lastwrap703`. Again, `lastwrap703` is specified as an ID and is a child of `mycontainer`.

It's also worth mentioning that [`.replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) will replace the whole element with the new content. This doesn't seem like what you're trying to achieve. As others have mentioned, [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) will replace the inner html of the matched element only.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/km6c87m3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
$( "#replaceoradd" ).click(function() {
alert("asdsads");
   if ($("#lastwrap703").length == 0) {  // doesn't exists
         var html = ' <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0"><h3>Second Item</h3></div>';
        $("#mycontainer").append(html);
    }
 else
 {
  $( "#lastwrap703").html( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
 }
});
 
});
</script>
```